# Kendo mobile back button not working

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, angular-kendo

I am building a single page PhoneGap application, I am using Angular Kendo.
For app navigation I am loading multiple html pages dynamical as per user operations.

I have a Kendo back button on every page to navigate to previous page as below:

```
<kendo-mobile-header >
   <kendo-mobile-nav-bar style="color:black;">
      <kendo-view-title style="color:white;">Test</kendo-view-title>
      <kendo-mobile-back-button id="back-button" style="color:white;" k-align="'left'">Back</kendo-mobile-back-button>
      <kendo-mobile-button style="color:white;" k-align="'right'" href="Test.html">Next</kendo-mobile-button>
   </kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
</kendo-mobile-header>
```

But I am not able to navigate to previous page when I click on back button, also I am not getting any error in console logs.

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: I am having a similar problem.  Even if i change to use kendo.mobile.application.navigate, it does not work.  I suggest you try navigating with the navigate operation and see if that affects things.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was able to solve this by prefixing the href with "/" and using  kendo.mobile.application.navigate.   I was able to diagnose this by looking at the history in the browser and seeing that there were two entries when there should have been one.  Also note that the use of hashbang in the application affects this.  I turned that off to make matching the correct url for history easier.